# JavaFX vs Silverligth vs Flash vs HTML5

Tags: silverlight, flash, javafx, html5

Собираюсь изучать на выбор что-то одно из выше перечисленного списка. Что предпочесть, чтобы не потерять время зря, изучая технологию, которая не имеет реального будущего рыночного успеха. Просьба, отвечая, обосновать свое мнение.

Answer (score 4):

Сейчас сам занимаюсь разработкой RIA и основываясь на некотором опыте могу сказать, что  из перечисленных технологий стоит смотреть в сторону JavaFX, так как платформа действительно очень мощная. Единственное НО - к выходу готовится 2 версия JavaFX, в которой скриптовый язык JavaFX будет заменен на классическую Java, что с одной стороны хорошо. но для начинающих очень плохо, ведь сейчас прийдется учить ненужный скриптовый язык.
Также хочу обратить ваше внимание на [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/). Не буду сильно рекламировать, это за меня на официальном сайте уже сделали, скажу только, что GWT позволяет писать приложения на Java, как обыкновенные десктопные приложения, а затем компилятор GWT транслирует код в JavaScript с AJAX асинхронными вызовами процедур. О кроссбраузерности беспокоится компилятор и самое приятное - не пользователю не нужно скачивать никаких дополнительных модулей.
Самый яркий пример возможностей GWT приложения - это [Google Wave](https://wave.google.com/).

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 - это открытый быстро развивающийся стандарт для веба. JavaFX, Silverligth, Flash возникли потому, что возможности предыдущего стандарта не покрывали увеличившихся потребностей пользователей. Когда сети были медленными, было достаточно показывать на странице текст и все были довольными. Когда сети стали быстрыми, появилось множество вещей (звук, видео, игры и т.п.), которых в стандарте не было. Поскольку изменение стандарта - дело небыстрое, производители программного обеспечения попытались предложить свое решение (и заработать на этом деньги). Так и появились JavaFX, Silverligth, Flash.

Сейчас, когда стандарт понемногу начинает включать в себя необходимое для современного уровня развития технологий, потребность в продуктах от сторонних производителей будет исчезать. Но это не произойдет одномоментно: пройдут годы прежде, чем исчезнут JavaFX, Silverligth, Flash. Все эти продукты поддерживаются крупными производителями: Oracle, Microsoft, Adobe, - и они будут интенсивно продвигать их на рынок. Поэтому многое зависит от горизонта планирования: если Вы думаете о том, какие навыки развивать и где работать в ближайшие два-три года, то просто просмотрите базу вакансий, что наиболее востребовано сейчас, то будет востребовано и через несколько лет.

HTML5 стоит особняком - это открытый стандарт и в то же время это продукт поддерживаемый Google и Apple. Именно за ним останется последнее слово. Уже сейчас Вы сможете оценить возможности HTML5. Например, просмотрите ролик [The Wilderness Downtown](http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/) (смотреть лучше в Хроме).

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX — это платформа для создания Rich Internet Applications (RIAs), которые могут запускаться на персональных компьютерах и мобильных устройствах.

Технология JavaFX позволяет создавать приложения для работы с мультимедийным контентом, графические интерфейсы пользователя для бизнес-приложений, игры для персональных компьютеров и мобильных устройств, насыщенные графикой, мультимедиа веб-сайты и др.

Совместное использование языков Java и JavaFX Script позволяет решать разнообразные задачи, например, логика бизнес-приложения может быть написана на Java, а графический интерфейс пользователя — на JavaFX Script.

Приложения, написанные на языке JavaFX Script могут запускаться на компьютерах с установленной средой исполнения Java 1.5 и выше. В настоящее время поддерживаются следующие операционные системы: Windows, Mac OS X, Linux и Solaris.